# Problem with implementing QuickSort with C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

So the answer turned out to be partially correct for this simple code. The result is "1
1
2
3
4
4
2
6
8
5
"
 I think the problem should be related to recursion and partitioning. Where did I do wrong??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void quick_sort(int num[], int low, int high){
    int i = low - 1;
    int pivot = num[high];
    for(int j = low; j <= high -1; j++){
        if(num[j] <= pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&num[i], &num[j]);
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    swap(&num[i+1], &num[high]);
    quick_sort(num, low, i);
    quick_sort(num, i+2, high);
    }
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {3,1,2,6,5,4,8,1,2,4};
    quick_sort(test, 0, sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0])-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); ++i){
        cout << test[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `low` starts at `0`, but `i` is `low - 1`. So on your first iteration, you have an index equal to `-1`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault I almost made the same jump, but he does at least a i++ in once in the loop before using it :) and every where else i+1 or i+2 so it is ok.. as far as that is concerned.

Comment: Why not step through the code in your favorite debugger, while watching the variables?

Comment: `using namespace std;` + `void swap(int* a, int* b)` isnt going to end well on the long run. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: See also: [C++ quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/2610810)

Comment: In the case where the pivot is the smallest value, you fall off the beginning of the range recusing `quick_sort(num, low, i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the for loop. The i value should be updated after the for loop completed, then use i value for swap and other quick_sort calls. But your source code, i updated inside the for loop and used it for swap and other quick_sort calls. It is the problem. Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void quick_sort(int num[], int low, int high) {
    if (low >= high) return;
    int i = low - 1;
    int pivot = num[high];
    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        if (num[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&num[i], &num[j]);
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    } // move to correct line
    swap(&num[i + 1], &num[high]);
    quick_sort(num, low, i);
    quick_sort(num, i + 2, high);
    // } this line should be moved to another line
}

int main() {
    int test[] = { 3,1,2,6,5,4,8,1,2,4 };
    quick_sort(test, 0, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]) - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]); ++i) {
        cout << test[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any difference from your for loop and mine.

Comment: Could you see it now?

Comment: You should probably edit this to not include `using namespace std;` and opt for the `std::` prefix instead. Especially for `swap`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Loc Tran pointed out, your pivot swap and subsequent left and right quick sorts must be outside for loop. There is no need of `else continue;`. The purpose of the for loop is to find the position(`i`) for our `pivot` element such that all elements to the left are smaller than `pivot` and to the right are larger that `pivot`.

Once the position(`i+1`) is identified, put the pivot there by swapping and then proceed quick sort on the left and right sides of `pivot`.

Also you should proceed quick sort only when `low < high`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void quick_sort(int num[], int low, int high){
    if(low >= high)
        return;
    int i = low - 1;
    int pivot = num[high];
    for(int j = low; j <= high -1; j++){
        if(num[j] <= pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&num[i], &num[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&num[i+1], &num[high]);
    quick_sort(num, low, i);
    quick_sort(num, i+2, high);
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {3,1,2,6,5,4,8,1,2,4};
    quick_sort(test, 0, sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0])-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); ++i){
        cout << test[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```